# Good DB schema for measurement units with php + zend?

Tags: php, sql, database, zend-framework, units-of-measurement

I am working on a web application that store a lot of measurement data.

These measures have different types like temperature, flow, weight, concentration...

I am currently trying to implement a **measurement units manager** to let the users of the application choose which unit they want for each measure.

The data is in multiple tables :

> Table1 : weightMeasure1 lengthMeasure1 TemperatureMeasure1
>
> Table2 : weightMeasure2 lengthMeasure2 FlowMeasure2
>
> Table3 : flowMeasure3

The users will be able to choose the unit that they want for each measure independently. So it will not be a **metric/imperial** choice.

All the data will be saved in there **SI or SI derived** unit in the Database. Because I am using **PHP** for my application I decided to use **[Zend_Measure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.measure.edit.html)** to handle the conversion (after asking this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753897/how-to-manage-measurement-units-in-a-php-web-application)).

---

### How to define the unit of each measures in my database?

### How to manage the user unit preferences?

---

*This is the best solution that I have so far :*

I will create a **property** table :

> property : property_id name column unit

- **property_id** is a unique incremented number (PK)
- **name** is a human readable name (optional)
- **column** is a concatenation of the table name and the column name (Unique constraint). For example : `table2_lengthMeasure2`
- **unit** is the Zend constant string defining the unit of the property in the database. For example : `SQUARE_METER`, `KILOGRAM_PER_HOUR`, ... more details available in the [Zend Framework API](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/).

I will create a **user_property_unit** table to manage the user preferences :

> user_property_unit : user_id property_id unit

- **unit** is the Zend constant string defining the unit of the property when it will be display in the UI for the user. For example it can be `SQUARE_METER` in the unit column of the `property` table and `SQUARE_FOOT` in the unit column of the `user_property_unit`

The problems that I see with this solution are:

- Using the concat of `table name + column name` seems not right to me...
- If I change the name of one of my columns it will not be reflected in the `property` table.

Thanks for your Help!!

---

UPDATE
 Is there any one why can help me even with some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have a separate table for PROPERTIES and a separate linking table TABLECOLUMNPROPERTY that makes a specific property the attribute of the column.

```
      PROPERTIES
      propid
      name
      unitid      FK references UNITS table


     TCP
     (tablename,columnname) composite PK
     propid


     UNITS
     unitid
     etc etc
```